# Would my weight be constant on Pluto?

Tags: gravity, pluto, charon

Since Pluto and Charon have distinct orbits around their barycenter (located approximately 960 km above Pluto's surface), the centripedal acceleration must be different on the outer hemisphere of Pluto (in relation to the barycenter).

Does that mean I would weigh less standing on the top of the outer hemisphere than I would standing on top of the inner hemisphere (facing the barycenter)?

Or is that cancelled out by the pull of Charon?

[image: Pluto-Charon System]

Comment: Should that read "I would weight _less_" rather than more?

Comment: @JamesThorpe - yep, corrected ;-)

Comment: I was halfway through writing a comment about Charon adding to the weight rather than cancelling it out when I realised that that was the wrong way round, which led me back to the more->less issue :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's try and do some math with this. Will use [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto) for numbers.

- Gravity at Pluto's surface: 0.61711215789 $m/s^2$
- Gravity from Charon- Pluto's near side- 0.0002724276 $m/s^2$
- Gravity from Charon- Pluto's far side- 0.00027242753 $m/s^2$
- [Centripetal Acceleration](http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/physics/circ/node6.html)- Near side- 0.00001749536
  $m/s^2$
- Centripetal Acceleration- Far side- 0.00006647414 $m/s^2$

For reference, the formulas to calculate these are as follows:

- Gravity- $a_g=G* m/d^2$ where $G=6.673×10^{-11} N m^2 kg^{-2}$. As $F=m*a$, this is basically the same as the gravitational equation, assuming a much smaller body than the primary mass.
- Centripetal- $a_c=v_t^2/r$. $v_t=2*\pi*r_{orbit}/orbital Period$

Bottom line, Charon's gravity has more of an effect than the Centripetal acceleration, but both are at least 3 orders of magnitude smaller than the base gravity. This is less than the [difference of weight in a person](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/42-our-solar-system/the-earth/gravity/94-does-your-weight-change-between-the-poles-and-the-equator-intermediate) from the equator to the poles.

Comment: So how many bags of space Doritos I eat will have more of an impact than Charon?

Comment: @corsiKa: The single-serving bags of Doritos are 1 oz or 28 grams. If you are the average weight (62 kg) then it would take about two to cancel out the effect of Charon on one side vs. Charon on the other.

Comment: Anothr aspect: On Earth, the tidal wave facing the Moon is the same height (I suppose) as the one opposite it, which indicates that the effect on the directly facing side should be the same as on the directly opposite side - but perpendicular to it, things are different

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen; Is it? The side of Earth facing the Moon is about 8000 miles closer to the Moon than the opposite side is, which results in a stronger tidal effect. Whether that results in a higher ocean tide, and by how much, is beyond my ability to calculate, but intuitively I'd expect there to be some difference.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto this is an interesting answer, though not at all my topic, could I ask you to elaborate a little on the equations used to derive the results please? I'd be interested to replicate them for the Earth-Moon just to be able to follow the other comments here.

Comment: Not a problem. Putting them together made me realize I missed one small step, so it helped the answer anyways!

Comment: Thanks, in fact I should have been more specific. Seeing your edit: the bit I am stuck on is how "Gravity from Charon- Pluto's near/far side is evaluated. Are you simply superposing 1) the acceleration ag as felt from Pluto whilst standing on its surface with 2) the ag as felt from Charon, again whilst standing on the surface of Pluto, where the ag from Charon has two possible values according to is position?

Comment: The distance at max is the diameter of Pluto different than at min.

Comment: Interesting. Despite the larger mass of Earth's moon its much greater distance dominates. Its hard to visualise two points together - that the relative acceleration due to the moon is a tenth of a Dorito by the earlier measure and yet it is also responsible for up to 15m tides.

Comment: The 15m tide is essentially a funnel effect. 1m is a more normal value. A part of this is because of the Sun, and a second part due to the repeatability of the motion, which has some resonance effects. And there are other effects too.

Comment: Very interesting answer! I would have though the acceleration meant more. Would you mind writing out the exact equation with numbers?